# Projecting PostGIS in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, postgresql

I have a layer (base layer) with MultiLineString geometries and now I need to project the layers (overlays) in the base layer from PostGIS using OpenLayers.

However, I got an idea how to project table data source into OpenLayers. I am trying it on topology schema and I am having my layer data in edge_data, node, faces, relations tables. Can anyone guide me how to project my topogeometry into OpenLayers?

And moreover, I am not using any servers except PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you want to do? To move between different projections you can use `ST_Transform()`. Many web-mapping tools use web-mercator - for example the google SRID for web-mapping is `900913`.

Comment: I am trying to project a table data source using GML in OpenLayers. And I am purely using PostGIS functions rather than any other tools/servers. With the help of Topology Schema I am trying and now I have a problem how to make topogeometry

Comment: from a table geometry which I have in query. I am not sure that whether going in a respected direction or not. Please guide me how to project a topological layer in OpenLayers via GML functions or any other way. I gone through functions like toGML()....etc. More idea requested.